# dynamically change querystring in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, rest, encryption, query-string, ihttpmodule

Our client is asking to encrypt the URL because it is passing values in the query string. We have used encryption and are able to encrypt the URL; however, existing code uses `querystring["var"]` in so many places and fails because of the encrypted URL. Hence, on page load, we will have to decrypt the URL. If I decrypt and alter the query string using `response.redirect`, then again query string will be visible in the URL and can be misused.

Please help.

**EDIT**
I was reading about RESTfull web service. I have not yet understood entire concept. I wonder if I can use this with my application to hide query string. Please let me know if so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this with little headache is to decrypt the query string as you currently do, then set its values to some object which can be stored in the session.  Storing it in a session variable would be useful if you wanted to exclude this information (hide) from the query string - you'd essentially be passing the data around behind the scenes.

Once stored in session, you would then change your code, such that wherever you use `querystring["var"]`, you will instead refer to the object that has been stored in the session.

***Edit***

Note, though, that this doesn't have to be relegated to a single value.  This object can have multiple properties each representing a query string value:

```
MyQueryStringObject myQueryStringObject = new MyQueryStringObject(SomeUrl);
//MyQueryStringObject decrypts the query string and assigns the values to properties in its constructor
string abc = myQueryStringObject.abc;
string xyz = myQueryStringObject.xyz;
```

Now, that uses properties to represent each query string value.  You may have tons of them.  In that case, you can store the values into some sort of `Dictionary` or a `NameValueCollection` perhaps.

There are various ways to achieve this which I think is beyond topic, but, note that the ***key*** to all of this, the very essence is to simply decrypt the url on the server (during postback) and save the unencrypted data into a session variable should you want to hide it from the URL.

Comment: Your logic is helpful if I have only one querystring["var"]. Howerver, my application is of almost 800 pages and there are different names are used inside query string. for example querystring["abc"]=1 and querystring["xyz"]=2. I am not sure about exact count but there are many more. Thanks anyways for your reply. please suggest some more idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much better way of going about this. I deal with a client with that has the same requirement. This class has soared through security scans as well.

```
Public Class QueryStringManager

    Public Shared Function BuildQueryString(ByVal url As String, ByVal queryStringValues As NameValueCollection) As String
        Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
        builder.Append(url & "?")
        Dim count = queryStringValues.Count
        If count > 0 Then

            For Each key In queryStringValues.AllKeys
                Dim value As String = queryStringValues(key)
                Dim param As String = BuildParameter(key, value)
                builder.Append(param)
            Next

        End If
        Return builder.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function DeconstructQueryString(ByVal Request As HttpRequest) As NameValueCollection
        Dim queryStringValues As New NameValueCollection

        For Each key In Request.QueryString.AllKeys
            Dim value As String = Request.QueryString(key)
            value = DeconstructParameter(value)
            queryStringValues.Add(key, value)
        Next

        Return queryStringValues
    End Function

    Private Shared Function BuildParameter(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String) As String
        Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
        builder.Append(key.ToString() & "=")
        value = GetSafeHtmlFragment(value)
        Dim encrypt As Security = New Security()
        value = encrypt.Encrypt(value)
        builder.Append(value)
        builder.Append("&")
        Return builder.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function DeconstructParameter(ByVal value As Object) As String
        Dim decrypt As New Security()
        value = decrypt.Decrypt(value)
        value = GetSafeHtmlFragment(value)
    End Function


End Class
```

**Use**

```
Dim nvc As NameValueCollection = New NameValueCollection()
nvc.Add("value", 1)
Dim builtUrl As String = QueryStringManager.BuildQueryString(url, nvc)
Response.Redirect(builtUrl, false);
```

---

Then when you get to the page you simply write:

```
Dim decryptedValues As NameValueCollection = QueryStringManager.DeconstructQueryString(Request)
```

The reason why I use `NameValueCollection` is because that's the same type as QueryString. You can build on to the class to add an object into the QueryString based on it's properties and their values as well. This keeps all of the complex and tedious logic encapsulated away.

Comment: Do everything David says, except Response.redirect, change that to Context.RewritePath (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx) - if you redirect, it will be in the querystring again